# Importing multiple Excel sheets in one table in SQL database, only one sheet has header

Tags: sql-server, ssms-17

I have an Excel file generated by another program that has multiple Excel sheets.
The column structure is the same except that just the first sheet has headers, the rest are just continuing from where the last sheet ended - it is an .xls format that allows only 65563 rows per sheet.

I want to import them in one table in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have some tutorial for you. It helps you to do it quickly to insert a record from Excel to database.

This is sample code:

```
    INSERT INTO Employee
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;
   Database=C:\DataFiles\EmployeeData1.xlsx',
   [vEmployee$]);
```

For more detail, visit this link: [tutorial link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-using-tsql-to-import-excel-data-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Or you can also do it by this way: [Tutorial for excel to database](https://sqlspreads.com/2017/05/04/how-to-insert-data-in-excel-to-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

Given below is the script to migrate data from Excel 2003:

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
,'Excel 4.0;Database=D:\test.xls','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

But, when the same code is used for Excel 2007 & above, it gives the following error:

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
,'Excel 4.0;Database=D:\test.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider “Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0” for linked server “(null)” reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider “Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0” for linked server “(null)”.

Lets solve this issue step by step.

Step 1 :
Download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010

Step 2 :
Install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 in your machine.

Step 3 :
Open SQL Server Management Studio. (If already open, close and re-open)

Step 4 :
Enable Ad hoc queries.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Step 5 :
Close the excel sheet that you need to import (if open).

Step 6 :
Give the correct path, file name and excel sheet name with $ sign in the script given below and execute the query.
This information must be correct.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\test.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');
```

If your first row has a column name then `“HDR=YES“`, else it should be No.

In case you need this query result in temporary tables, given below is the script to insert Excel records into temp table.

```
SELECT * into Temp FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\test.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');
```

Or, similarly...

```
---- Has column names
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\test.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');

---- Does not have column names
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet2$]');

---- Does not have column names
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet3$]');
```